# How do I suppress INFO messages when using Kafka in Java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, log4j

I use Apache Kafka client in Java and now I'm getting a lot of messages with [INFO] mark. All the suggestions I've found on the Internet are of changing log4j output level. But I don't use log4j.

A small part of output:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version: 2.2.0

[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId: 05fcfde8f69b0349

[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=group3] Subscribed to topic(s): test.topics.tasks
```

UPDATE:
I use org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.2.0

Comment: Is there any special framework you use? I recently had the same problem but the solution was specific for Quarkus.

Comment: To help we need to know which build system you are using (maven, gradle, other) and exactly which kafka library you are using. Just because you are not using log4j does not mean the kafka library is not.

Comment: I don't use any special framework. Just Java + Kafka client 2.2.0. I don't use any build system. I just use Maven to get Kafka client. I build a jar file in Idea without using Maven or Gradle.

Comment: If you look at Kafka-client's [dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/2.2.0), you'll see `slf4j-api`, that is a logging framework. So if you don't use logging explicitly, it doesn't mean that it's not used at all.

Comment: Yes, Kafka client use slf4j. I haven't been knowing it's a logging framework. Would you be so kind to suggest me how to suppress its INFO messages?

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't use log4j.

Maybe *you* don't, but some library that you pull, probably does (for example, Spring).

You should consult the documentation for the framework that you use (if any), otherwise, you can add your own `log4j.properties` file into your classpath like so.

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
```

Comment: As it has come to my knowledge Kafka client uses slf4j as a logging framework but I don't know how to suppress its INFO messages.

Comment: Slf4j is only an interface (simple logging facade). Kafka includes the Slf4j-log4j bridge, so you would add a log4j.properties file

Comment: Can I do that programmatically?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You're running a consumer or producer Java application. Why can't you package a resource file as part of that code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programmatically by adding this line in your code `System.setProperty(org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL_KEY, "off");`

This is because Kafka is using sl4j for logging, so disabling sl4j logging will suppress info messages. If you wish to log for other levels/purposes, you can replace "off" with one of these: "trace", "debug", "info", "warn", "error" based on https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html